# How to check if a string is accepted by a context-sensitive grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Is there an algorithm to determine membership in context-sensitive grammars?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators#Context-sensitive_grammars) lists a couple of libraries that parse context-sensitive grammars, so you could try to extract the algorithm from those -- or just use the libraries if what you really want is an implementation. Hopefully, somebody will provide a proper algorithmic answer.

Comment: Otherwise, Google ("[parsing context-sensitive grammars](https://www.google.com/search?q=parsing+context-sensitive+grammars)") suggests some resources. If you find your answer there, it would be great if you could come back and write an answer summarizing what you learnt. The key search term is "parsing".